# CloudDeploy does not work with IntervalSlider

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

I try to deploy the following simple Manipulate:

```
m = Manipulate[rate,

 {{rate, {13, 13}}, 0, 30, ControlType -> IntervalSlider, Method -> "Stop"},
 SaveDefinitions -> True]

CloudDeploy[m, Permissions -> "Public"]
```

But it only shows me the static image of the IntervalSlider, the slider doesn't work.

Does this mean CloudDeploy simply does not support the IntervalSlider?